# Laravel 5: redirect to an external link outside of localhost/server

Tags: php, dropbox-api, laravel-5

I want to build an app with laravel 5 & dropbox API in which I want the API allow/cancel-warning to be displayed when you land on the homepage, not when you click a button.
I tried different methods but I couldn`t make it work.

```
public function start(){
        session(['user_id'=>1]);
        $dKey = 'key';
        $dSecret = 'secret';
        $appName = 'app';

        $appInfo = new Dropbox\AppInfo($dKey,$dSecret);

        //store csrf token
        $tokenStore = new  Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION,'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
        //define auth details
        $this->webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'http://localhost:8000/dropbox/finish',$tokenStore);
        $this->checkSession();
    }

    public function checkSession(){
        $users = User::where('id','=',session('user_id'))->get();

        if(isset($user[0]->dropbox_token)){

        }
        else{
            $url = $this->webAuth->start();

            //return Redirect::to($url);
            //return Redirect::away($url);
            //header('Location : '.$url);
        }

    }
```

The link in $url exists and its valid.

These(last 3 commented methods) are the methods i tried , including return redirect($url),is it possible to do this or am i wasting my time with this ?please help me out.

Comment: When you say "I couldn't make it work," what specifically happened (for each of the things you tried)? From a cursory glance at the Laravel docs, I think that `return redirect()->away($url);` should be right. Have you tried that?

Comment: (Perhaps `Redirect::away($url)` is the same thing... what actually happens when you try that?)

Comment: Oh, maybe you're missing a `return` in `start()`? It should probably be `return $this->checkSession();`.

Answer (score 39):

This code works for me:

```
return redirect()->away('https://www.dropbox.com');
```

Make sure you also add a return (i.e. `return $this->checkSession();`) in `start()`.

Answer (score 9):

Below code will work

```
return redirect()->away('http://www.paypal.com');
```

And this will also work.

```
return redirect('http://www.paypal.com');
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing with WSO2 as an IdP and my Application Server which is Ubuntu-Based s Service Provider. I am using mod_auth_mellon with Laravel and I keep on getting 500 server error. I had thought these suggestions will work for me but it doesn't seem like it. So frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

For https and such use the following

```
return redirect()->to($refererUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do this,

```
use Redirect;

return Redirect::to('your url');
```

Or just,

```
return \Redirect::to('your url');
```