# How to redirect to url in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5 on local on window ..i am trying to redirect the page to some external url..but nothing seems to help me..

i tried

```
                   return \Response::make('',302)->header('Location','http://site2');
                    return redirect()->away("http://site2");

                    \Redirect::to('http://site2');
                    header('Location: http://site2');
```

but none of them working..gives no response..

Comment: Findings:
core php function to redirect to external url 

return header('Location: http://someurl.com');

dont works within laravel..:)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
return redirect()->away('http://site2');
```

Make sure you also add a return (i.e. `return $this->checkSession();`) in `start()`.

Comment: return redirect()->away("http://site2"); working fine from routes.php but not working in controller

Comment: Did you check this "Make sure you also add a return (i.e. return $this->checkSession();) in start()."

Comment: sorry i could not understood this..
my code is
return redirect()->away("http://site2");

Comment: solved...there was some other problem in my code..which is solved now :) btw thanks

Comment: so what was the problem ? And if you think this answer is useful then please upvote it so that it can be useful to others as well

Comment: This answer appears to have been copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158074/laravel-5-redirect-to-an-external-link-outisde-of-localhost-server so the bit about `$this->checkSession` doesn't apply in your case. However, `return redirect()->away('http://site2');` or `return Redirect::away('http://site2');` should both work as long as there isn't something else returning before it. If it doesn't work, please update your question with the error / outcome received.

Comment: actually in routes.php
Route::get('320-{slug}.html',['as'=>'music.download_song_320', function($slug){
    $misc = new \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\MiscController;
    return $convert_song = $misc->convertSong($slug,'320');

}]);
i did not added return ..so it was causing problems

Comment: my vote will not be counted as my reputation is 14.. sorry for this

Comment: @Joseph How can you say that i copied answer from that URL ? I know how to redirect to extra link in laravel 5 buddy . So, when i saw that i just post the think that i know.