# Why is return redirect giving 404 in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I want to display the video by redirecting it to my site. But when I try using return redirect I get a 404 error. If I try echo instead of return, it first outputs the URL and then displays the video. My question is why when I use to return it gives 404. How can I accomplish this using return?

**The problem is not only for the video, I also face the same problem when I want to show a map from google. Why is it giving 404 when using return redirect?**

**web.php(Routes)**

```
Route::middleware([Localization::class])->group(function () {
  $lang = RouteLocalization::lang();
  $csrf = Config::get('custom.csrf');
  Route::get('/', 'Welcome@setWelcome');
    
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['isLogin']], function () use ($lang) {
    Route::prefix($lang)->group(function () {
      .
      .
      .
      Route::get(__('route.interactivity_preview'), 'Interactivity@get_preview')->name('interactivity_preview');
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
}
```

**Interactivity Controller**

```
public function get_preview() {
    .
    .
    .
    if (!(strpos($url, 'www.youtube.com/watch') === false)) {
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
        $data['url'] = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $query['v'];
        return redirect()->away($data['url']);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I try echo instead of return, the video is displayed after the output.

```
echo redirect()->away($data['url']);
```

**Echo Output Example**

> HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache, private Date: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 07:08:46 GMT Location: https://www.youtube.com/embed/yk-lHYTVJo0 Redirecting to https://www.youtube.com/embed/yk-lHYTVJo0. Redirecting to https://www.youtube.com/embed/yk-lHYTVJo0.

How do I solve the problem using return or how do I get the video to come directly without output when I use echo?

Comment: how are you using this route?

Comment: Route::get(__('route.interactivity_preview'), 'Interactivity@get_preview')->name('interactivity_preview');

Comment: That's the declaration, and it looks very strange as well. I was more asking how you are using the route e.g. do you expect users to directly visit the URL that the route resolves to ?

Comment: Users are not visiting the url. The added video is displayed on the site. In other words, the video is displayed at the current location without leaving the site.

Comment: You mean in an iframe or something like that?

Comment: Yes i use it that way.

Comment: It's usually good form to actually share the relevant parts in the question like e.g. the route definition as well as the view code that uses it. Also I would advise against using `__` in the route since the locale may not have been selected at the point where the route is defined

Answer (score 0):

Try using redirect to:

```
return redirect()->to($data['url']);
```

You can also use it directly:

```
return redirect($data['url']);
```

Also try with it if above don't work for you:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

return Redirect::to($data['url']);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Not working.  it gave 404 error again

Comment: Please visit this link you may find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158074/laravel-5-redirect-to-an-external-link-outside-of-localhost-server

Comment: 404 error means page is not found. Please make sure your url is correct. And also check about the sessions of url.

Comment: The url is correct but when I try with echo the video is displayed. Why doesn't it return?

Comment: May be video loading is causing this problem but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
return redirect($data['url']);
```